# How to manage ssl connection when network service changes

Tags: android, networking, ssl

I'm playing around with an [open source project](http://beem-project.com/projects/beem/repository) in hopes that I can offer a fix for a bug I submitted that's driving me nuts. The short version is that if change network service, the app dies. This occurs (slightly differently) when:

- I walk from WiFi coverage to 4g or vice-versa
- I connect via WiFi with the client and then turn WiFi off, failing over to 4g

I thought the issue might be with the app's `isConnected` method, which returns:

```
return ni != null && ni.isConnected();
```

Which I updated (in local SDK) to:

```
return ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

But once I actually switched to hardware device instead of virtual, I now see the error is with SSL connection.  I can't tell if the issue is that it's running constantly so will always be "interrupted", or if there should be some sort of try/catch or if the connection simply needs some mechanism in place to reconnect rather than vomit and pull the app down.

Hoping for a quick fix, I went looking for how SSL is managed/enabled for a connection, but instead found a lot of frustrated workarounds.

Here is the immediate error in the SDK log.

> 08-06 03:38:48.795: W/InputEventReceiver(16140): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
>   08-06 03:38:57.744: W/System.err(16140): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x4144cb18: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
>   08-06 03:38:57.744: W/System.err(16140):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
>   08-06 03:38:57.744: W/System.err(16140):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:651)

What I'm wondering is if there is a prescribed method for handling non-HTTP SSL/TLS open connections when Network Service switches. I imagine a new handshake needs to happen, but is there a `.isFading()` or similar broadcast info to gracefully hang an app until connection switches or is officially gone?